# How to set Google Chrome as default web browser in Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome

After installing Google Chrome on **Lubuntu 20.04** I launched the Google Chrome web browser and it shows me the `default browser` alert, and definitely I press it and I expect it works like other versions of Ubuntu or Lubuntu, but for this latest version it doesn't work, each time the alert is showed and on the calling web browser lovely Firefox is opened, so **How I can make the Google Chrome as default web browser?**

Comment: The Lubuntu manual shows *Default Applications* within *Session Settings* with a drop-down for Web Browser... https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html?highlight=default%20browser or https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/_images/default-app-tabs.png   That would be my first recommended way  (though not all are shown; it's not detecting my installed `chromium` snap for example)

Comment: Dear @guiverc, unfortunately, the `session settings` doesn't show the Google Chrome inside the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `google-chrome-stable` the default web browser, you should follow the below steps:

1. Press Lubuntu `start on the taskbar` **>** `Preferences` **>** `Alternative Configurator`
2. Then you should see below window:

   [image]
3. Click on the second option, the Google Chrome
4. leave the sudo password
5. Click on <kbd>Auto</kbd> button to make it as default web browser.

Comment: I don't like your first sentence (of your answer) so I'd recommend removing that.  Lubuntu switched from LXDE to LXQt & I don't see *merging* point. FYI: The original LXDE is ~dead (GTK3 was heavier so it was then ported to Qt), the LXDE-Qt team members merged with Razor-Qt creating LXQt but that's upstream of Lubuntu (*and not Lubuntu*). The other posts are for different DEs, and Lubuntu 20.04 LTS is now the 4th release of Lubuntu using LXQt (ie. it's been the same since Lubuntu 18.10)

Comment: Dear @guiverc, If it is not correct please edit it. because I get the merge word from `The LXQt name derives from the merger of the LXDE and Razor-qt projects` in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu)

Comment: My dear friend @guiverc, I ask you to edit. really I don't know what should I write.

Comment: I have lubuntu 20.04 and brave and it does not work. Brave is selected as default one with higher priority 200 (firefox 40).

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: @TN888, Sorry for hearing that.

Comment: @AmerllicA no problem my friend. Once I figure out a solution, I'm gonna post it here as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TN888, please post it and I will upvote it, even maybe tick it as correct one.

Comment: @AmerllicA, cool.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I went to `Lubuntu Start → Preferences → LXQt settings → Session Settings → Default Applications` and chose `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` as my default web browser. **Notice**: it won't take effect until next session login.

[Default Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPmcc.png)